# How to inject dependency in abstract class with NestJs?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

Let's say I have an abstract service like bellow

```js
abstract class AbstractService {
  @InjectConnection() connection: Connection
}
```

and `UserService` will extends `AbstractService`

```js
class UserService extends AbstractService {
  async get () {
    this.connection //undefined
  }
}
```

I cannot access the connection when I extend AbstractService but it works with a single class

```js
class UserService {
  @InjectConnection() connection: Connection
  async get () {
    this.connection //mongoose connection
  }
}
```

and I call UserService#get in the controller

```js
@Controller(ROUTER.USER)
export class UserController{
  constructor(private readonly service: UserService) { }
  @Get()
  get() {
    return this.service.get
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `UserService#get`?

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel I call UserService#get in the controller, I added code for the controller. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when `UserService` extends `AbstractService` it will extend all its members such as methods or constructor but it will not do for `connection` because it is a decorator that has to be injected that is why `this.connection` is `undefined` in the first example, so you have to deal with that.
in the second example, `UserService` does not extend anything and has its own `connection` so it works that's obvious, but we need to extend `AbstractService` so we can use its methods.
one solution is to make `UserService` has its own `connection`, and once created call the parent class constructor passing `connection` to it.
 in this case, the `get()` method will return the expected connection:

```js
abstract class AbstractService {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() connection: Connection) {}
}
```

```js
class UserService extends AbstractService {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() connection: Connection) {
    super(connection);
  }
async get() {
    this.connection
  }
}
```

Comment: Hí @Hatana thanks for your answer, every service I need inject connection, anyway to make the code cleaner? Thanks.

Comment: @luongvy have a look I updated my answer.